# jhipster and liquibase timeout

Tags: java, mysql, liquibase, jhipster

Surfing on the internet yesterday, I this awesome new tool that generate a full stack app with few command lines : jhipster.

I followed the different guide, but when I try to start my app (mvn spring-boot:run), when liquibase tries to "talk" with the DB I have a 30000ms timeout.

MYSQL is, of course running on my machine.

I have searched on the internet and it seems that it's a problem of "removeAbandonedTimeout".

The exact error line is :

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: Timeout of 30000ms encountered waiting for connection.
```

This is the actual stack of my error :
[image]

I hope you can help me using this awesome tool that seems to be really powerful.

Thanks a lot for advance

Answer (score 0):

You can look at application-dev.yml or application-prod.yml and set database configuration there.

You have to create database first before invoking mvn spring-boot:run